# Python Timer Callback Method

Tags: python

```
from threading import Timer

class test_timer():
    def __init__(self):
        self.awesum="hh"
        self.timer = Timer(1,self.say_hello,args=["WOW"])
    def say_hello(self,message):
        self.awesum=message
        print 'HIHIHIIHIH'
        print message
        raise Exception("hi")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'Got to main'
    x=test_timer()
```

When I run the code above, my callback method is never triggered. I have been trying to solve this for hours but cannot figure it out >.<

To test, the timer. I run this code and check to see if x.awesum is 'WOW'

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You never start the timer. You need to:

```
self.timer.start()
```